# how to get matplotlib physical (not data) scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this simple code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
PlotFileName="test.pdf"
pdf = PdfPages(PlotFileName)
fig=plt.figure(1)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.xlim([0,10])
plt.ylim([0,10])
ax1.plot([0,10],[0,10])
e=0.0
theta=0
maj_ax=2
min_ax=maj_ax*np.sqrt(1-e**2)
const=1
ax1.add_artist(Ellipse((5, 5), maj_ax, const*min_ax, angle=theta, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black",zorder=2, alpha=0.5))
plt.grid()
pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
plt.close()
```

Here is how it looks:
[image]

As you see from the code, it should be a circle, but it isn't! I have narrowed the problem down to the `const` term in line 16. I don't want to use `ax1.axis("equal")` because my data don't have the same scales on the vertical and horizontal. Could any one tell me how I can ask matplotlib to tell me what aspect ratio it is using so I can set the `const` term correctly so I have a circle in the end?

In other words I want to know the ratio of the horizontal to the vertical axis "physical" length (for example, what is printed out).

I would really appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance

Comment: Is using `F=pylab.gcf()` and `DefSize = F.get_size_inches()` the best way? In this manner: the aspect ratio is: `DefSize[0]/DefSize[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to explicitly define the figure size... you may also need to specify the subplot parameters if you are using non-default settings. Adjust figsize and subplot parameters as needed for non-equal horizontal and vertical scales. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9)
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, xlim=(-2.5,12.5), ylim=(0,10))
ax1.plot((0,10), (0,10))
maj_ax, e, theta = 2, 0, 0
min_ax = maj_ax * np.sqrt(1 - e**2)
ax1.add_artist(Ellipse((5, 5), maj_ax, min_ax, angle=theta, 
                       fc="green", ec="black", zorder=2, alpha=0.5))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```